# Расширить компонеты interface builder доп. Атрибутом . Категории

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

Добрый день, изучаю xcode
Требуется для визуальных компонентов добавить доп. атрибут theme. Написал следующий класс, но ни как не пойму как создать правильно getter и setter для работы с instance переменной объекта. Как я понимаю, обьявленная мной переменная _theme является static. 
Спасибо @"Max Mikheyenko" за информацию: Ограничения при создании категорий: Невозможно создание переменных! Вопрос остается: как добавить setter и getter theme для работы с User defined run time attributes in Xcode?

NSView.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface NSView (FrameworkAdditions)

@property (nonatomic, assign) IBInspectable NSString *theme;
- (void) changeTheme;

@end
```

NSView.m

```
#import "NSView.h"

@implementation NSView(FrameworkAdditions)

NSString * _theme;

-(void) setTheme:(NSString *)theme
{
    _theme = theme;
    [self changeTheme];
}

-(NSString *) theme{
    return _theme;
}

- (void) changeTheme {
    NSLog(@"Get %@ %@", [self theme], self.view);
}

@end
```

Comment: в .m ничего вообще делать не надо. @property должно быть достаточно

Comment: Тогда приложение ругается: Failed to set (theme) user defined inspected property on (NSView): [<NSView 0x6000001214a0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key theme. Дело наверное в объявлении NSView(FrameworkAdditions) , что как я понимаю, расширяет стандартнуую реализацию NSView

Comment: а почему у вас nsstring прописан assign

Comment: @Max , что предлагаете? пробовал различные варианты...

Comment: ну либо strong, либо ничего, поскольку strong все равно дефолт

Comment: Исправил.Аналогичная ситуация, Issue: Property 'theme' requires method 'theme' to be defined - use dynamic or provide a method implementation in this category. Ни dynamic , ни.synthesize в корне не меняют ситуацию

Comment: ах ты ж, это категория. не заметил